# i need Database table creating

Tags: database, oracle

i created my tables and I'm stuck at the last one,
here is the tables that been created correctly

```
CREATE TABLE Staff ( 
    Staff_ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    First_Name VARCHAR(50), 
    Last_Name VARCHAR(50), 
    Username VARCHAR(10), 
    Password VARCHAR(10), 
    Address VARCHAR(30) 
)

CREATE TABLE Category ( 
    Category_ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    Name VARCHAR(30) 
)

CREATE TABLE Author ( 
    Author_ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    First_Name VARCHAR(50), 
    Last_Name VARCHAR(50), 
    Birth_Place VARCHAR(30), 
    Birth_Date DATE
)

CREATE TABLE Publisher ( 
    Publisher_ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    Name VARCHAR(50) 
)
```

and this is the one I'm getting an error :

```
CREATE TABLE Book ( 
    Book_ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    Title VARCHAR(50), 
    Edition INT(30), 
    Year_Published INT(4), 
    FOREIGN KEY (Publisher_ID) REFERENCES Publisher(Publisher_ID), 
    FOREIGN KEY (Author_ID) REFERENCES Author(Author_ID), 
    FOREIGN KEY (Category_ID) REFERENCES Category(Category_ID) 
)
```

the error says:

> "ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis"

Comment: don't Spam tags

Comment: That error message comes from Oracle. Why is the question tagged `mysql` instead of `oracle`?

Comment: Sorry, this is the first time i use the website

Comment: Oracle was tagged @hassan removed it

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial on creating foreign keys in Oracle: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/foreign_keys/foreign_keys.php Now compare your syntax to what's in the tutorial.

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile That's because you spammed with several different database tags, and he guessed the wrong ones to remove.

Comment: i tried removing the foreign keys and the error is the same so i think the error is somewhere else

Comment: CREATE TABLE Book ( Book_ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, Title VARCHAR(50), Edition INT(30), Year_Published INT(4) ) ////////////////////////////////////////////// i tried only creating the table and still the error

Comment: I'm sorry about the tags! Could anyone now help me please?

Comment: @Barmar me spammed? this is not my question and I did not even touched any tag

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Sorry, misread you as the OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

INT can not have a scale associated with it so YEAR_PUBLISHED and EDITION are incorrect definitions.
I believe that, generally, you would be better off sticking to NUMBER for numeric datatypes, eg NUMBER(4), NUMBER(30).

In the database the INT datatype is simply a sub-type of NUMBER so you aren't gaining anything by using it:

```
type NUMBER is NUMBER_BASE;
subtype INTEGER is NUMBER(38,0);
subtype INT is INTEGER;
```

If you want to see the definitions for the various 'other' numeric datatypes take a look at the SYS.STANDARD package.

Comment: Thank you so much, apparently you're right .. i deleted the columns Year Published and edition and the table was created

Comment: @MissSHOOSH - The more important question is what SHOULD those columns be. Syntax rules are one thing, the meaning of your data and how it should be structured is far and away more important. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

- The `INT` data type does not have a precision.
- You also need to define the `Publisher_ID`, `Author_ID` and `Category_ID` columns.
- It is good practice to name your constraints.
- A `PRIMARY KEY` column is both `NOT NULL` and `UNIQUE` so you do not need to include a second `NOT NULL` constraint.

Like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Book ( 
    Book_ID        INT CONSTRAINT Book__Book_id__PK PRIMARY KEY, 
    Title          VARCHAR(50), 
    Edition        INT, 
    Year_Published INT, 
    Publisher_ID   INT CONSTRAINT Book__Publisher_ID__FK REFERENCES Publisher(Publisher_ID), 
    Author_ID      INT CONSTRAINT Book__Author_id__FK    REFERENCES Author(Author_ID), 
    Category_ID    INT CONSTRAINT Book__category_ID__FK  REFERENCES Category(Category_ID) 
);
```